# (iphone) Where do I increment a version number for application update?

Tags: ios, xcode

I see "bundle version" in xcode.
Do I increment this number & compile and submit it?

besides testing 'update version' works fine,
What are the steps to submit an update to a live application?

-edit-
Besides, some posts say testing update on simulator is just as good as installing new ipa over old ipa through itunes for testing update.

ie, are the steps below sufficient for application update testing?

Install version1 through xcode simulator
do some testing/data insertion on version1.
Install version2 through xcode simulaotr

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you need to edit the bundle version in order to submit updates for a live application. The way it works is that the iOS devices recognize your app via its bundle identifier (that's why it's so unique: com.YourName/CompanyName.AppName), and if a device installs an app with the same bundle identifier, but a greater bundle version, the old app is replaced with the new version.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you need to edit the bundle version. You can do this from the project-editor view in Xcode 4, or directly inside app's Info.plist file.

Answer (score 1):

For some automation you can pick up this great Jeff Le Marche script that automatically increases the the build number:

http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.com/2011/07/auto-incrementing-build-numbers-for.html